# Dynamic content in a Microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, microsites

I'm trying to build a microsite page with dynamic content based on information I have in a DE. Users will see different elements of the page depending on the amount of fields the user has in the DE; is this possible within Marketing Cloud? Can I set my ampscript variables based on the rows in a DE?

I know it's possible within an email but I can't get the functionality to work with a microsite, is there a way to retrieve data from a DE In a similar way to retrieving data from a salesforce object?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize personalization strings and AMPScript inside of a Cloudpage no problem. The hardest part is passing the values along.

SFMC has included an AMPScript function to assist called [CloudPagesURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) which will pass all the personalization strings and attributes attached to the subscriber into the Cloud Page.  This would be used in the email like so `<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL('1245'))=%%" >link</a>`.

This will allow you to use your personalizaton strings like `%%emailaddr%%` as well as any attributes or data extension columns same as you could in an email.

You can also manually pass variables inside of an URL parameter by adding a query string to the end of the url, like so `http://www.link.com?myvar=myval` where `?myvar=myval` is the string, placing a parameter of myvar to the value of myval.  This can then be retrieved on the page using the [RequestParameter()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) Ampscript function.

Finally you can also use Lookups and Retrieves on SF objects via AMPScript to pull values as well, same as you can inside of an email.

Comment: Almost 10k;) ....

Comment: @Data_Kid - I know! So close I can taste it... ha ha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Yes, you can. You can use AMPSCript in Microsite as you use it in Email including retrieving data from a salesforce ojbect.

```
Set @rows2 = LookupOrderedRows("Cars",4,"Horsepower Desc","MPG",Field(@cardata,"MPG"))

%%[ var @rs
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west')
]%%
```